# Find anchor link's position dynamically

Tags: php, html, wordpress, anchor

I can't find any issue or a solution about that on the internet. You know some accordion elements push down the rest of the page when clicked on the title and displaying the content. Contents may have different heights, maybe there are more than one accordion elements in a page (faq etc). The problem is when a content is extended, anchor links scroll to the wrong place. Is there anyone has the same issue, a solution or a way to prevent that? A way to calculate the anchor links position dynamically?

It happens on Wordpress btw.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see you're new. Try and always post a sample of your code to show what you have tried. Your answer relies on a minimum of 3 different technologies.

Comment: It doesn' t matter what code you use, it's a general issue. When a hidden content is extended, standart html anchor links don't work properly if the page size is changed dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Without any actual example provided, here's a solution:

[Bootstrap 4 - Collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

[Bootstrap 4 IDE - Pingendo](https://pingendo.com/) for you to learn how to create some awesome stuff.